# How to Use PCA to Reduce Dimension

Tags: opencv, pca

**Input :** LBP Feature extracted from an image with  dimension 75520, so the input LBP data contains 1 row and 75520 columns.

**Required Output:** Apply PCA on input to reduce the dimension,

Currently my code look like,

```
void PCA_DimensionReduction(Mat &src, Mat &dst){

    int PCA_DIMENSON_VAL 40
    Mat tmp = src.reshape(1,1); //1 rows X 75520 cols
    Mat projection_result;
    Mat input_feature_vector;
    Mat norm_tmp;
    normalize(tmp,input_feature_vector,0,1,NORM_MINMAX,CV_32FC1);
    PCA pca(input_feature_vector,Mat(),CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, PCA_DIMENSON_VAL);
    pca.project(input_feature_vector,projection_result);
    dst = projection_result.reshape(1,1);
}
```

Basically I am using this features to match similarity between two images, but I am not getting proper result as without applying PCA.

Any help will be appreciated...

Regards

Haris...

Comment: hi-dim lbp, cool ;) but shouldn't you train one big pca (offline) for all images ? not one per image ?

Comment: hi, @Haris, actually, i'm playing with the same idea, atm. went all the way from pca to random-projections, then to walsh-hadamard, not forgetting wavelets, finally towards a simple dft -> throw_out_hf -> dft_back, but in the end - not using lbp(u) but a much shorter four-patch-lbp feature(16 bins only, instead of 256[or even 59 for lbpu], and then skipping any feature compression) worked better for me. comments ? ;)

Comment: i'd be also curious, how you solved the : 'IntraFace not available' problem ;) (my main problem atm is to find a good replacement for that ...)

Comment: Hi @berak thanks for reply,regarding your first comment, I am following the implementation [here](http://bcsiriuschen.github.io/High-Dimensional-LBP/), but no idea how to use PCA to reduce dimension. Currently I am getting feature vector of size 75520, but confused with how to make it input for PCA.

Comment: Hi, I have some query about your second comment, in your four-patch-lbp feature extraction, how do you patch face?, are you considering the entire face?, or based on some land-mark?

Comment: in the very same way as for the lbpu version. 4x4 patches a 10pixels around a landmark point (currently using [dlib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dclib/files/dlib/) for the landmarks)

Comment: Actually I am not getting the accuracy as they said in their paper for LFW, what about you?.

Comment: neither do i. ~0.83 is the best i can get, using [opencv's benchmark](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/datasets/samples/fr_lfw_benchmark.cpp).

Comment: I just tested  [dlib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dclib/files/dlib/) and giving better landmark detection on LFW, I am thinking of using dlib for landmark detection instead of intraface, what you think?. Have you got good result with it ?

Comment: only downside is the 95mb pretrained model ;)  - like said before, 0.83 using 20dlib landmarks -> hi-dim fplbp -> svm. what are your results ? ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68225/discussion-between-haris-and-berak).

Comment: sure, why not. cya there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### you will have to collect feature vectors from a *lot* of images, make a single pca from that (offline), and later use the mean & eigenvectors for the projection.

```
// let's say, you have collected 10 feature vectors a 30 elements.
// flatten them to a single row (reshape(1,1)) and push_back into a big Data Mat

Mat D(10,30,CV_32F); // 10 rows(features) a 30 elements
randu(D,0,10);       // only for the simulation here
cerr << D.size() << endl;
// [30 x 10]


// now make a pca, that will only retain 6 eigenvectors
// so the later projections are shortened to 6 elements:

PCA p(D,Mat(),CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW,6);
cerr << p.eigenvectors.size() << endl;
// [30 x 6]

// now, that the training step is done, we can use it to
// shorten feature vectors:
// either keep the PCA around for projecting:

// a random test vector, 
Mat v(1,30,CV_32F);
randu(v,0,30);

// pca projection:
Mat vp = p.project(v);

cerr << vp.size() << endl;
cerr << vp << endl;
// [6 x 1]
// [-4.7032223, 0.67155731, 15.192059, -8.1542597, -4.5874329, -3.7452228]


// or, maybe, save the pca.mean and pca.eigenvectors only, and do your own projection:

Mat vp2 = (v - mean) * eigenvectors.t();

cerr << vp2.size() << endl;
cerr << vp2 << endl;
//[6 x 1]
//[-4.7032223, 0.67155731, 15.192059, -8.1542597, -4.5874329, -3.7452228]
```

well, oh, here's the downside: calculating a pca from 4.4k train images a 75k feature elements will take like a good day  ;)

Comment: Hi, @berak thanks for the answer, I will try to understand your answer, but before that one more question, suppose I have to compare two images,like load img1-> calculate LBP(1X75520) -> apply PCA to reduce dimension, then the same procedure for img2, finally compare PCA output of img1 and img2 for similarity.

Comment: yes, exactly. you compare the projected(shortened) features for 2 images.

Comment: btw, what about intraface ?

Comment: I got the library somewhere else from github with an open source project.

Comment: ah, ok. i see. linux binary only, unfortunately.

Comment: So I can take `PCA.eigenvectors` as my PCA output.

Comment: you need to save pca.mean and pca.eigenvectors. the later projection is then: subtract the mean from your feature, and multiply with the transposed eigenvectors.